# How to load a .bin model file?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch, dlib

Recently, I have been working on a age and gender recognition problem. Upon searching for already existing solution I came across an Open Vino Toolkit. 
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/

They uses many models for deep learning tasks and one of them is
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_models_intel_age_gender_recognition_retail_0013_description_age_gender_recognition_retail_0013.html

Now these models are free to use and can be easily downloaded. I downloaded the model zip folder and it contains one .xml file. this file shows the layers and dimensions in each layers and other useful things about the structure of the model.
The other file is .bin file and this (i guess) is the real model file but I dont how to load a model saved as .bin file.

[The image attached contain the content of the .xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgar7.png)
Need help.

Comment: having the same issue in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

you should install openvino toolkit in your pc. and find the `object_detecction_ssd.py` file in the deployment tools folder which would stored in installation folder of openvino toolkit. Then you can pass the XMl and bin file to the python file as a arguments.